# jquery set noConflict (or equivalent) BEFORE the jquery script include

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question: Is there a "built-in" or "easy" way to set the jQuery namespace *before* the jquery.js script include?

Reason I ask is because I'm working on a script that utilizes the jQuery library, and the script is to go on a page that has a library that uses the `$` namespace already.  Normally I can just use `jQuery.noConflict()` except the problem is, there is code on the page (which I cannot control) that hooks into mouse movement events and other stuff that basically triggers calls to the 3rd party code over and over the entire time, so often in fact, that more often than not, js errors are happening between the time the jQuery script is loaded and the `.noConflict()` call is made.  *I cannot control or change that 3rd party script.*

So basically I need the jQuery object to be instantiated without ever taking `$` namespace in the first place.  Now.. I'm certain that I could reverse engineer jquery.js and make it not do that, but before I go down that road, I figured surely others have come across this situation.. but I could find no official documentation on jQuery for setting this before the script include; only after.  But I figured surely others have come across a problem like this anyways, but I can't seem to find any existing questions detailing this (it could be that I just suck at googling).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**Edit**:

To be clear, this is basically the order in which I need things to happen:

```
<script src='thirdpartyscript.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src='jquery.js'></script>
```

I obviously can't call `jQuery.noConflict()` before the `jquery.js` script include, since the `jQuery` object/method doesn't exist yet.

But I can't call it *after* the script include, because between time it takes for `jquery.js` to fully execute and the `noConflict` call to be made, `thirdpartyscript` is already throwing errors because jquery took control of `$`, even for just that one single microsecond or w/e.

So.. I know I can edit `jquery.js` to *never* use `$` namespace, but I was wondering if there was a built-in way or otherwise easy hack to do it before the `jquery.js` script include, because a) I don't want to hack `jquery.js` itself, because I'd like to keep pointing to code.jquery.com instead of maintaining my own instance, b) doing so involves actually figuring out what to change (which in fairness I did a quick eyeballing and it doesn't look like much. mostly my caveat is with point "a")

Comment: Do you mean as in using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})` instead of `$(document)`.. etc?

Comment: @null well yes, my overall goal is to do that, but most immediately my issue is to get around jQuery screwing with the `$` namespace at all when it's initially loaded in the actual jquery.js include. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

wont work. The object "jQuery" is not available if you include the lib  later. You can create an smart "Watcher" for that.

```
<script src='thirdpartyscript.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Start an interval
    var watch = setInterval(function() {
        // Check if jQuery available
        if(typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined') {
            // Stop the interval
            clearInterval(watch);

            jQuery.noConflict();
        }
    }, 500);
</script>

<script src='jquery.js'></script>
```

Comment: no i'm sorry but..this is worse than just calling it after the script include. This leaves for potentially bigger gaps between the time jquery.js loads and noConflict is called.

Comment: I need something that will make jquery.js NOT touch `$` AT ALL. And it's looking like the only way to do this is to alter jquery.js itself, which is what I was hoping to avoid